# Esri Silverlight control. How do I bind layer similar to Bing maps?

Tags: xaml, silverlight, binding, esri

I'm switching out of Bing Maps into ESRI but have hard time finding sample which will do the same thing..

I have layer on top of base map showing position of assets. Data bound via MVVM.

This is code from Bing Maps:

```
<m:MapItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource WorkLayerData}}">
  <m:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Canvas .. coordinate properties
       .... STUFF drawn here.....

      </Canvas>                                               
    </DataTemplate>
  </m:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</m:MapItemsControl>
```

I figured that most close is ElementLayer in ESRI Silverlight control, but can't figure out how to bind it to my datasource and achieve similar result.

I can't even post what I've tried because all samples I found on ESRI website just do static elements, but I need to bind collection.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to be using an Esri `FeatureLayer`, which can connect to either a MapService (if you use an Esri map server) or a spatial data service.

Have you looked at the online samples here?

https://developers.arcgis.com/silverlight/sample-code/start.htm#FeatureLayerSimple

Comment: Yes, But I have this data, its on my server and I store it locally

Comment: All I need is to display a layer. If I have to upload data to Esri server in order to display it - it doesn't make sense then..

Comment: Notice it can connect to either a MapService OR a spatial data service ... if you have the data on your own server then how are you serving it up? Through a service? Can you make that service a spatial service? AFAIK you don't need to go for a full-on MapService.

Comment: Preferably need to be done without bunch of refactoring. Right now data loaded from server (doesn't really matter HOW) and I have it as a n array of objects. Objects have different attributes and Lat/Lon is just 2 of them that's used right now with BingMaps control to place my UI on a map. It's not just a dot. Point here is that I bind to templated UI. Map just needs X/Y to place container and other stuff being drawn dynamically based on different properties.

Comment: Seems like I can use ElementLayer, but have to add elements programmatically if it's not fixed stuff. Each of those elements I bind - clickable to show popup with more data. Whole layer is interactive. It's just like you bind ListView, but elements positioned where need to be by Lat/Lon

Comment: Ok what about a GraphicsLayer, and you create a graphic for each of your datapoints? You can set a MapTip, or handle a graphic click to do whatever it is you want to do.

Comment: So, how do I set ItemsSource and bind GraphicsLayer? Is there any sample?

Comment: Did you look at the link to the Silverlight samples? Here's a link into the 'graphics' section, which may be of use ... https://developers.arcgis.com/silverlight/sample-code/start.htm#UsingPointDataSource

Answer (score 1):

The SL SDK comes with a Bing Maps layer out of the box.

See the Bing Maps sample here:
https://developers.arcgis.com/silverlight/sample-code/start.htm#BingImagery

Essentially it's:

```
<esri:Map>
    <bing:TileLayer Token="INSERT_MY_BING_KEY_HERE" LayerStyle="Road" />
</esri:Map>
```

Comment: dotMorten, This is not a question. I mentioned I'm switching away from Bing maps control. I'm trying to bind my custom layer of push pins to ESRI control but can't figure out how. Sample on how I did it with bing provided.. Nothing to do with base map display